# Вопрос по конструкции sizeof (тип)?

Tags: c

Преобразование типа выглядит как (тип) объект. Конструкция sizeof при желании узнать размер типа, тип заключается в круглые скобки. Есть ли тут связь. То есть (тип) что-то возвращает или как-то так(да, я представляю на сколько тупой вопрос).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну если только по круглым скобкам.

- sizeof - оператор языка Си ([Википедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%8B_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%B2_C))
- преобразование типов - конструкция языка для явного приведения типов (еще раз [Википедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B0))

В двух словах - записанный тобою код проходит несколько стадий, прежде чем стать исполняемым. В итоге рано или поздно код превратиться в простые машинные инструкции вида `переместить А в Б`, `прочитать из адреса В в Г`, `перейти на адрес Д, если флаг CPU установлен` и так далее. Конкретно инструкции зависят от компилятора и называются машинными кодами, записывать их принято на ассемблере.

Так вот, `sizeof()` это подсчет размера, занимаемого чем угодно - что ты подставишь в скобках. Почему нельзя просто писать для `int` допустим цифру 4, а для `char` допустим цифру 1? Потому что не на всех архитектурах, для которых есть компиляторы С/С++, эти типы имеют именно этот размер. Даже при переходе с x86 архитектуры на какой-нибудь MIPS/RISC или ARM чувствуется разница в компиляторах - не говоря уже о совсем разных инструкциях ассемблера у каждого из процессоров.

В итоге при сборке вместо `sizeof(X)` компилятор **подставит** число, соответствующее именно для этого компилятора и именно в текущей его конфигурации размеру этого самого `X`.

А приведение типов сделано для решения всевозможных задач и написания костылей. Например, функция должна сложить `signed int` и `unsigned int`, чего делать нельзя - старший бит первого отвечает за знак, и второго просто хранит часть значения. Сложить? Нельзя, смысл разный. Компилятор не может решать такие вещи (так как рискует потерять один бит), и выдает сообщение Warning: арифметика с signed и unsigned числами, могут быть проблемы. Однако если программист уверен, он ставит приведение типа (или увеличивает разрядность, или еще что-то придумывает) - и Warning пропадает.

Самое частое применение приведения типа в Си - это операции с указателями и загадочный тип `void`, вернее указатель на него `void*`. Но это из раздела черной магии, лучше такими вещами без наставника не заниматься.

Связь есть? Ну обе штуки работают с типами, да.

Answer (score 1):

Нет, никакой связи нет. Просто синтаксис оператора `sizeof` в применении к имени типа требует заключения имени типа в `()`.

Можно также обратить внимание, что вторая форма оператора `sizeof` - `sizeof` в применении к результату выражения - скобок в своем синтаксисе не имеет вообще. Например, `sizeof "abc"`.

P.S. Меня удивляет тот факт, что вы предположили аналогию с *преобразованием типа*. Тут скорее можно усмотреть аналогию с *вызовом функции*, который делается через оператор `()`. Но и с вызовом функции никакой связи нет.